# Errors in code to build string date

Tags: java, string, date, enums

```
package pass;
import java.lang.*;

public class Date{
    private Mois mois;

    public String date(String d){
        int year=Integer.parseInt(d.substring(0,4));
        int mount=Integer.parseInt(d.substring(5,7));
        int day=Integer.parseInt(d.substring(8));
        moi = Mois(mount);
        String mois=moi.toString();
        return ""+mois+" "+day+", "+year;


    }
    public enum Mois{
        January(1),
        February(2),
        March(3),
        April(4),
        May(5),
        June(6),
        July(7),
        August(8),
        September(9),
        October(10),
        November(11),
        December(12);

    private int mois;

    public Mois(int k){
        this.mois=k;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return this.toString();
    }

    }
}
```

I need a java code return a string date

I cant use Date format ,, only string

input "2017-01-15" String should return "January 15, 2017" String?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I know that linking outside is frowned upon, but really, a 2 second Google search tells me this:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm

Comment: This has been answered *many* times already. Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: @EgorZhuk i edited my question

Comment: @durbnpoisn 
input "2017-01-15" String should return "January 15, 2017" String

true but i need a string input and string output

Comment: I need it without Date format
@durbnpoisn

Comment: The requirement not to use a date formatter is a rather critical part of your question. Please update your question to say exactly what you are allowed to use and what problem you have with your existing code.

Comment: @MohamdEl-Saleh, nice to see that you have put a real effort into your question this time. Next things to learn may be to detail your constraints in the question, and maybe more importantly, when asking for debugging help, to specify the exact problem or error you have with your code. Quote your error message precisely in the question, and it will but much easier to understand what you’re really asking about and much easier to guide you. It means more than you think. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and specify format in it.

Conversion using today's date:

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy"); 
String s = formatter.format(new Date());
System.out.println(s);
```

Output

```
February 22, 2017
```

Conversion from String date:

```
String date="2017-01-15";
DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
Format formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy"); 
String t = formatter2.format(formatter1.parse(date));
System.out.println(t);
```

Output

```
January 15, 2017
```

Formatting using Java 8

```
    String date="2017-01-15";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    LocalDate ldate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter1);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yy"); 
    String s = ldate.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: I dont want to do it with Date format ,Only string

Comment: @MohamdEl-Saleh I have updated the code. I hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @tom My bad :) , just updated the code.

Comment: @Leozeo, if we were to teach the asker about standard classes for dates, we should least do the favour of teaching the Java 8 `java.time` classes. `DateFormat` and `Date` are outdated and often also complicated to work with.

Comment: @OleV.V. Added code snippet for Java 8 too.

Comment: Nice, @Leozeo, thanks (so did I, a few seconds before you).

Answer (score 0):

As you may have guessed, your problem is with trying to create an `enum` constant outside the enum through `Mois(mount)`. An `enum` guarantees that there is always exactly 1 instance of each constant in your JVM, so you cannot do that.

Fortunately, in your case there is an easy way around it. Your months are numbered 1 through 12. At the same time, all the constants in an `enum` are already numbered, only from 0 (so through 11 in this case). So to get `Mois` number `mount`, just do:

```
    Mois moi = Mois.values()[mount - 1];
```

`values()` returns an array containing all the constants. I subtract 1 from `mount` to convert from your 1-based numbering to Java’s 0-based.

There are a few minor issues in your code too. Better fix them to get the thing working:

- You cannot do `public Mois(int k)` in an `enum`; your IDE probably already told you. An `enum` constructor must be private. I understand why you tried `public`, but with the fix above we no longer need that, we can just declare it `private`.
- Your `toString` method calls itself recursively leading to an infinite recursion. Just delete the method. `enum`s have default `toString` methods that do as you expect.
- You have two declarations of a variable named `mois`. Just delete the instance variable `private Mois mois;`. Again, with the above fix you don’t need it.

Now when I call `date("2017-01-15")`, I get `January 15, 2017`.

I understand that you are not allowed to use standard classes, so I suggest that the above is your answer. For anyone else, in the real world one *would* probably want to use Java’s standard classes for date manupulation. Since Java 8, one should do something like:

```
    String output = LocalDate.parse(inputDateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd", Locale.ROOT))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ROOT));
```

Choose an appropriate locale (or leave out the two locale arguments to use the computer’s defaut). If you wanted day-of-month to have prefixed zero for days 1 through 9 (`01` through `09`), you would use `dd` in the second formatting pattern.